# Changed database to Postgres, now Rspec throwing errors: can't find object by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, testing, rspec

I've formatted my computer and while reinstalling Rails changed my database to postgres, and now a few tests that were previously passing are failing, for example the following code:

```
describe "Tickets" do
  subject { page }

  describe "when creating a new ticket successfully" do
    before do
      login_as_user
      visit new_ticket_path
      fill_in "Subject", with: "Test ticket"
      fill_in "Description", with: "This is a test ticket"
      select 'Billing', from: "ticket[category]" 
      click_button "Submit Ticket"
      TicketNotifier.drain
      Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.drain
    end

    specify { last_email.to.should include("my.email@gmail.com") }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: "Ticket #1") }
    it { should have_content("ticket has been submitted successfully") }
  end
end
```

Returns the following errors:

```
  10) Tickets when creating a new ticket successfully 
     Failure/Error: TicketNotifier.drain
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Ticket with id=366
     # ./app/workers/ticket_notifier.rb:5:in `perform'
     # ./spec/requests/blas_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

   # same error repeated a few times...
```

Or:

```
context "should not be able to edit other user's website" do
  before { visit edit_rental_path(1) }

  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Your Websites") }
  it { should have_selector(notice, text: "You do not have access to this domain.") }
end
```

Throwing a few of the following:

```
  2) Websites create a user with 2 websites log user out log in second user should not be able to edit other user's website 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_website_path(1) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Website with id=1
     # ./app/controllers/websites_controller.rb:116:in `correct_user'
     # ./spec/requests/websites_spec.rb:187:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, is it creating a new object for every `it { should ... }` clause?
Even when I try something like the following it can't find by id:

```
@site = Website.where(link: "http://google.com").first
visit website_path(@site)
```

What has changed that's creating these issues?

#### Update

I've emptied my gemset as suggested by depa and now I don't get errors for the first test I posted, even when I specify `it { should have_selector('title', text: "Ticket #1") }`. The `#1` comes from the ID of the ticket, so for some reason it's working on those tests like it used to, but I'm still getting errors on others unless I change them to:

```
before do
   # create the ticket
   @ticket = Ticket.where(...).first
end

it { should have_selector('h2', text: "Ticket ##{@ticket.id}") }
```

Whereas previously if I just left it as `Ticket #1` the tests would pass. Do `postgres` and `sqlite` work differently as test databases?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried purging the test database and trying again but it didn't help.

Comment: I would try resetting your gem environment, starting from `gem pristine rspec-rails` and `gem pristine capybara` and going as far as `rvm gemset empty` if you use RVM.

Comment: Check that `click_button "Submit Ticket"` successfully submitted.

Comment: @depa I followed your advise, fixed some issues but still getting other errors. I've updated my question. Joshua the ticket is getting submitted successfully, see updated question.

Comment: Nice! I made an answer from my comment since it helped you with the original error. I would not be surprised if sqlite and postgres worked differently as test databases...

Comment: *"Do postgres and sqlite work differently as test databases?"*. Yes. Both databases can behave differently in a variety of ways. Without seeing the actual generated SQL and the data it's operating on it is rather hard to be specific about anything more.

Answer (score 1):

I would try resetting your gem environment, starting from `gem pristine rspec-rails` and `gem pristine capybara` and going as far as `rvm gemset empty` if you use RVM.